# iron-image prevent-load not working off of data path binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

`!editState(uploadState.*, index, 'edited')` is true but yet `prevent-load` is not working and the request still fires. It's not a issue with a simple boolean variable binding, only with data path. Why isn't `prevent-load` working off of this data path binding?

```
        <iron-image
            hidden$="[[!editState(uploadState.*, index, 'edited')]]"
            prevent-load="[[!editState(uploadState.*, index, 'edited')]]"
            src="[[getImage(uploadState.*, index, 'value')]]"
            sizing="cover"
            class="image-show">
          </iron-image>

  properties: {
    uploadState: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(5));
        var newArray = arr.map(()=> {
          return {
            value: false,
            main: false,
            edited: false,
            loading: false
          };
        });
        return newArray;
      },
      notify: true
    },

`
```

Comment: What version of the element are you using?

Comment: How does you editState function look like? Have you checked that it gets called?

Comment: @MichaelStramel 1.2.5

Comment: @PascalL. `return this.get(\`uploadState.${index}.edited\`);` which I verified the value with console.log before return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are referring to was an outstanding issue in the iron-image 1.x element. You can update to the latest 2.1.1 version for the fix. This element​ is hybrid so it will work with Polymer 1.x and 2.0.

Comment: Oh...didn't know  hybrid elements worked with 1.0. Thanks! Are you sure though?...the original issue was prevent-load not working at all because of `src`. Mine is only with datapath.  I will try it tonight.

Comment: The goal of hybrid elements is that you can slowly convert apps to 2.0 instead of having to do a bunch of changes all at once. I feel confident that it will work based on the code you posted in the original question. If it doesn't work, I may need more info on your setup to help out

Comment: So it worked...sort of. On the initial first display, it will incorrectly try to load the image even though the value is `edited: false` by default. But when mutating `edited` afterwards it detects the changes and behaves according to true or false.